# "немалое" or "не малое"?

Tags: грамматика

> Уважение к нему и сейчас в стране существует, и немалое.

or

> Уважение к нему и сейчас в стране существует, и не малое.

Comment: *немалое*, since it means *большое* with which it can be theoretically replaced, *не малое* would be correct if the sentence contained a contrast *не малое, а большое*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, “не” with adjectives and participles is quite tricky in Russian.
So, even large part of native speakers cannot write it properly very often.

Basically you write “не” seprately if:

- you have some **strengthening** word or phrase (like “далеко не”, “отнюдь не”, “вовсе не”, “ничуть не”, “нисколько не”, etc) near the main word;
- you have some **antithesis** (after the main statement) that opposes the primary meaning;
- you want to imply some antithesis or strengthening *implicitly* without writing them (sort of the author’s grammar).

For example:

- strengthening “совсем не малое”:

  > Уважение к нему и сейчас в стране существует, и совсем не малое.
- explicit opposition „не малое, а …“:

  > Уважение к нему и сейчас в стране существует, и не малое, а довольно значительное.

In your “short” case you most likely shoud use “немалое”.

---

In common usage one can apply the rule of thumb as follows:

*If you can replace “не”-something in sentence with a one-word synonym (not containing “не” prefix) without losing any meaning and context, you should write it as one word.*

> Уважение к нему и сейчас в стране существует, и значительное.

More information about “не” you can find in grammar rules (in Russian):
https://therules.ru/hyphen-particles/#88
(§ 88 and so on)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has been said, one trick for deciding how to write *не* with an adjective -- слитно or раздельно -- is by examining whether *не* together with its adjective assert/affirm a property of the noun phrase, in which case you should write them *слитно*, or reject/deny it (i.e. property), in which case it is *раздельно*.

Telling the difference between the two can be sometimes quite tricky, but in your example it's quite obvious that *немалое* should be chosen -- you are clearly asserting that this man is of notable repute rather than trying to dismiss the claim that there's little respect for him.

To show how *не малое* can pop up in a setting similar to the one you provide, imagine a dialogue:

> Person А: Уважение к нему сейчас в стране малое.
>
> Person В: Неправда, не малое...

The word *малое* can be said to be out of place in this particular Person A's phrase and in need of being changed for, say, *маленькое*, but style is not the important thing here. The important thing is that *не* and *малое* are written раздельно in Person B's response -- for the very reason that Person B is not asserting that the man is held in high respect, but denying that respect for him is low.